# I can not use "pip"

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip

My environment is Ubuntu18.10 and python2.7.  I want to use "pip", But I can not use pip. I tried this. What should we do?

```
python -m pip install requets 

/usr/bin/python: No module named pip

sudo apt-get purge -y python2.7-pip
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python2.7-pip
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python2.7-pip'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python2.7-pip'

sudo apt-get install python2.7-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python2.7-pip
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python2.7-pip'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python2.7-pip'
```

Comment: I enter 'sudo apt-get install python-pip', I was succesfull.

Comment: Like I said before my comment was deleted: Selcuk closed this prematurely.  You have several different options, *including* `sudo apt-get install python-pip`.  I'm glad that worked for you, and I'm sorry my other notes (perhaps useful to somebody else) got deleted.